# Is there possibility to get all virtual machines available in Azure DevOps environment?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Hello I would like to get all machines available in a specific environment and use them as a parameter in the YAML pipeline (e.g. I've got 20 machines and I would like to get them all and see available to choose from when I run the pipeline)

Comment: I will check it tomorrow thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there possibility to get all virtual machines available in Azure DevOps environment?

The answer is yes.

To see available to choose those 20 machines from when you run the pipeline, you need to create private agent pool for those 20 machines.

As you can see from the azure pipeline:

[image]

We can see that the option to choose from is **agent pool**. So, if we want get those 20 machines all and see available to choose from when you run the pipeline, you need to create a private with a private agent pool on each machine. In this case, you will get those 20 machines all and see available to choose.

You could check the document [Self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) for some more details.

Comment: It's not what I meant, I was talking about gathering all VMs in Pipelines > Environment > "Environment Name" in one "variable" and later see them in the pipeline run

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to create a self hosted agent in Kubernetes cluster.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops

It's easier to manage and Autoscaler